# Can't understand React 'unmounted' component definition

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand my component behavior..
Here is my example:

```
const Component = (props) => {

  const [bigClass, setBig] = useState('')

  const name = (props.dir === 'right') ? 'right' : 'left'

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout')
      setBig(' big')
    }, 3000);
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className={"App-logo " + name + bigClass} alt="logo" />
      </header>
    </div>
  )
}


function App() {
  const [dir, setDir] = useState(true)
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {dir ? <Component dir='right' /> : <Component dir='left' />}
      <button onClick={() => setDir(!dir)}> CHANGE ROTATION</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

As I supposed at first inner App 'setDir' state changes on every button click and App will re-render with new instances of Component every tieme. Therefore It will be re-render with initial bigClass = '' state. But actually it stay ' big' with other re-renders after first setTimeout

My questions:

1. Am I right that JSX looks at my {dir ?  : } statement like on one component and change only it 'dir' prop?
2. Is there a beautiful way to make different . I've fount this, but it's not so tricky:

```
  {!dir ? null : <Component dir='left' />}
  {!dir ? <Component dir='right' /> : null}
```

Comment: You might be seeing weird results because the `setTimeout` isn't canceled when you update `dir`, so previous instances may be affecting future ones. Best practice is to provide a cleanup function as the second argument to `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `1.` question but it's cleaner to just change the props directly:

2.

```
// this :
  {!dir ? null : <Component dir='left' />}
  {!dir ? <Component dir='right' /> : null}
// could simply be:
   <Component dir={dir ? 'left' : 'right'} />
```

Now your `unmounted` warning probably comes from the `setTimeout` in the `useEffect`

You always want to give react a way to cleanup pending timeouts if the component was removed:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // save the timeout id in a variable
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout')
      setBig(' big')
    }, 3000);
    // return a callback in useEffect that clear the timeout
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not a problem, I need different components and bigClass='' on every button click. In your suggestion it will be the same component

Comment: Well in your code you show the same component, how are we supposed to help if we don't have the actual code ?

Comment: Code is actual) I think you don't understand me. I said about the same or different instances (object) of Component class. When react read JSX <Component /> it initialize instance of Component class in virtual DOM. My questions was how can I make mount new instance of Component on button click and unmount old. In your example <Component dir={dir ? 'left' : 'right'} /> it will be the same object and it's bigClass will be the same on every re-render